# A Weird Computation Result from Python

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a crule1.py as follows.

```
 def exp_rule1 (mu1, h, alpha):
     return h**2/(4*mu1**2)
```

Then I run it in the Interpreter.  I got

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Imported NumPy 1.8.0, SciPy 0.13.3, Matplotlib 1.3.1
Type "scientific" for more details.
>>> import crul1 as c1
>>> c1.exp_rule1(1, 1, 0)
0
```

Then I copy the code into interpreter. The result is

```
>>> def  exp_rule1 (mu1, h, alpha):
...      return h**2/(4*mu1**2)
... 
>>> exp_rule1(1, 1, 0)
0.25
```

It makes me very confused and I cannot fix it. You are very appreciated to point out the problem in this code.

Comment: both instances running python 2?

Comment: Define "interpreter". Are you running the second in the same shell as the `import cru1 as c1`, `c1.exp_rule1(1, 1, 0)` lines?

Comment: Yes, I run the same shell. The version is Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, `/` returns an integer value if both its operands are integers. As a special case, `n/d` is 0 if `n < d` and both are positive.

For

```
def exp_rule1 (mu1, h, alpha):
    return h**2/(4*mu1**2)
```

you want to ensure that either the numerator or denominator is a floating point value. A simple way to do that is to make the `4` a float instead of an integer.

```
def exp_rule1 (mu1, h, alpha):
    return h**2/(4.0*mu1**2)
```

Another solution is to import the new 3.x behavior for `/`, which is to always return a float regardless of the operands. If you do this, replace any divisions where you rely on integer division with `//` instead.

```
# This allows 1/2 to return 0.5 instead of 0
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're mixing integers and floats. Try making the call `exp_rule1(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)` and you'll get the right result. Just make sure all the arguments to the function are floats.

Comment: But both cases appear to mix integers and floats in the same way, don't they?

Comment: Specifically, you are doing integer division instead of float division. 1/2 is zero for ints, .5 for floats.